# PHP Imagick class working when called from Web Server but not from Command Line

Tags: php, imagick

I'm running into a very frustrating problem when using Imagick in PHP.

Simple code:

```
$image = '1551660111_7801.jpg';
$imageBG = new Imagick();
$imageBG->readImage($image);
$imageBG->resizeImage('1280', '720', 1, 1, true);
$imageBG->writeImage ('test.jpg');
```

When I run this via Chrome, no issues, generates the new file.

But when I run through terminal like this

```
php test.php
```

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in ../test.php on line 8
```

Comment: Its most likley the path. check if the path from where you call this file is the same as the web browser would call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your PHP version on CLI and on web server.

on cli:

```
php -v
```

on web server open phpinfo(); command in some *.php file.
It is possible that you have installed ImageMagick as PHP 5.6 extension and it is used by web server, but you CLI php version is PHP7

Comment: Ahh when I run in CLI it says PHP 5.6.30 but my web server is running 7.2.10. I'm using MAMP for local web server. How do I change what PHP version runs on command line?

Comment: just type: `php7.2 test.php` instead of `php test.php`. I dont know how it works in MacOS but it works like that in linux CLI

Comment: Thanks mate! All sorted

Answer (score 0):

The path to the included file has to fit for both calls. 
Make sure you call the test.php from the same path as a web browser would.